# how to perform a case-insensitive attribute selector in xquery

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I'm trying to query an XML column in SQL server, and I want to select records where an attribute value matches a case-insensitive string.

For instance, consider the following value for the XML column:

```
<items>
  <item k="Description" v="hello" />
</items>
```

Right now, my select looks like this:

```
SELECT
MyXmlColumn.value('(/items/item[@k="Description"]/@v)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as v
FROM Table
```

The problem is that the value of the "k" attribute could be 'Description', 'description', or 'DESCRIPTION'.

How do I write the XQuery so that it performs a case-insensitive match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [lower-case function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645589.aspx) `fn:lower-case` (which will make the attributes you are searching on lower-case) and then make sure that in your query you use lower-case:

```
SELECT 
MyXmlColumn.value('(/items/item[fn:lower-case(@k)="description"]/@v)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as v
FROM [Table]
```